# Magento1.9 : moving webserver to new web server location

Tags: magento-1.9

Already have installed our magento 1.9 in Following Configuration

Magento ver = 1.9

Ubuntu = 12.04

Apache 2 = 2.2.22

php = 5.4.45

We have to plan move to webserver to new web server Following Configuation

ubuntu = 18.04

Apache2 = 2.4.29

php = 7.2.10

Can you please suggest me Above configuation support to magento1.9

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your configuration is correct for Magento 1.9 but you need to install [Inchoo Patches for Php 7.2](https://inchoo.net/magento/magento-1-official-php-7-2-patches/).